# Angular 5 have error on first compile (error: TS2339), but after success compilation all works fine

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I wrote not typical code for case, where I get some information from API server, but don't know, how looks all response fields. After getting response I should create form for update this and sending back. 
Because I don't know all `ngModel`s, I generate some fields dynamically after response and assign it to `ngModel` in cycle in my template.
After stopping my `ng serve -o` on next first start up my Angular 5 app I get compile error. If I comment problem's code, compile, and after that uncomment it - all works fine.

order.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../user/user.service';
import {OrderService} from './order.service';
import {enumUserTypes} from '../user/user.model';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap} from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import {Order} from './order.model';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order',
  templateUrl: './order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order.component.scss']
})
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
  orderContent = [];
  edit: boolean;
  userTypes = enumUserTypes;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    public userService: UserService,
    public orderService: OrderService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.orderService.getOrder(params.get('orderId'))).subscribe(response => {
      this.orderService.order = response;
    });
    this.edit = false;
  }


  editOrder() {
    for (let item in this.orderService.order.orderContent) {
      if (this.orderService.order.orderContent.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        let newClassFieldName: string = this.orderService.order.orderContent[item].className;
        let newClassFieldLabel: string = this.orderService.order.orderContent[item].label;
        let newClassFieldValue: string = this.orderService.order.orderContent[item].value;
        this[newClassFieldName] = {
          className: newClassFieldName as string,
          label: newClassFieldLabel as string,
          value: newClassFieldValue as string
        };
        this.orderContent.push({
          className: this[newClassFieldName].className,
          label: this[newClassFieldName].label,
          value: this[newClassFieldName].value
        });
      }
    }
    this.edit = true;
  }

  submit() {
    this.orderContent = [];
    for (let item in this) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(item) &&
        item.substring(0, 17) === 'orderContentField') {
        this.orderContent.push({
// error TS2339: Property 'className' does not exist on type 'this[keyof this]'.
          className: this[item].className,
// error TS2339: Property 'label' does not exist on type 'this[keyof this]'.
          label: this[item].label,
//  error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'this[keyof this]'.
          value: this[item].value
        });
      }
    }
    this.orderService.order.orderDataUpdate = new Date();
    this.orderService.updateOrder(
      this.userService.user.userId,
      this.orderService.order.orderName,
      this.orderService.order.orderCost,
      this.orderContent).subscribe(response => {
    });
  }

  saveEditsOrder() {
    this.edit = false;
  }

}
```

order.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="this.edit" class="wrapper--order--edit-form">
  <form class="form" #OrderEditPageForm="ngForm" novalidate>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of this.orderService.order.orderContent">
      <label class="label" for="{{item.className}}">{{item.label}}</label>
      <input class="input"
             [(ngModel)]="this[item.className].value"
             id="{{item.className}}"
             name="{{item.className}}"/>
    </ng-container>
    <button class="btn"
            type="submit"
            role="button"
            (click)="submit()">
      Send
    </button>
  </form>
```

order.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Order} from './order.model';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {UserService} from '../user/user.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {apiRoutes} from '../app.config';

@Injectable()
export class OrderService {
  order: Order = new Order();

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private httpClient: HttpClient,
              public userService: UserService) {
  }


  createOrder(userId: number, orderName: string, orderCost: number, orderContent: any): Observable<Order> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Order>(apiRoutes.orders,
      {
        userId: userId,
        orderName: orderName,
        orderCost: orderCost,
        isOrderOpen: this.order.isOrderOpen,
        isOrderPaidOf: this.order.isOrderPaidOf,
        orderWorkStatus: this.order.orderWorkStatus,
        orderPaymentStatus: this.order.orderPaymentStatus,
        orderDataOpened: this.order.orderDataOpened,
        orderDataUpdate: this.order.orderDataUpdate,
        orderDataClosed: this.order.orderDataClosed,
        orderDataPayment: this.order.orderDataPayment,
        conversationId: this.order.conversationId,
        orderContent: orderContent
      });
  }

  updateOrder(userId: number, orderName: string, orderCost: number, orderContent: any): Observable<Order> {
    return this.httpClient.put<Order>(apiRoutes.order + this.order._id,
      {
        userId: userId,
        orderName: orderName,
        orderCost: orderCost,
        isOrderOpen: this.order.isOrderOpen,
        isOrderPaidOf: this.order.isOrderPaidOf,
        orderWorkStatus: this.order.orderWorkStatus,
        orderPaymentStatus: this.order.orderPaymentStatus,
        orderDataOpened: this.order.orderDataOpened,
        orderDataUpdate: this.order.orderDataUpdate,
        orderDataClosed: this.order.orderDataClosed,
        orderDataPayment: this.order.orderDataPayment,
        conversationId: this.order.conversationId,
        orderContent: orderContent
      });
  }

  getUserOrders(): Observable<Order> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Order>(apiRoutes.userOrders, {userEmail: this.userService.user.userEmail});
  }

  getOrder(id: string): Observable<Order> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Order>(apiRoutes.order + id);
  }

}
```

order.model.ts

```
export class Order {
  constructor(
    public _id: number = null,
    public userId: number = null,
    public orderName: string = '',
    public orderCost: number = null,
    public isOrderOpen: boolean = true,
    public isOrderPaidOf: boolean = false,
    public orderWorkStatus: string = 'Checking documents',
    public orderPaymentStatus: string = 'Not paid',
    public orderDataOpened: Date = new Date(),
    public orderDataUpdate: Date = null,
    public orderDataClosed: Date = null,
    public orderDataPayment: Date = null,
    public conversationId: number = null,
    public orderContent: Object = []
  ) {
  }
}
```

I get some error on new fields creating after getting response API.

`Errors TS2339: Property 'className' does not exist on type 'this[keyof this]'.`

`Error TS2339: Property 'label' does not exist on type 'this[keyof this]'.`

`Error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'this[keyof this]'.`

How can I solve this? 
I should something switch off this checking in compiler or reformat my code?

Comment: Your english is hardly readable (I don't want to offend you, just keep reading), so you really should give us your whole code. Because right now, all I see in your code is that you loop over your class properties, and I really don't understand what you're trying to do, but it's certainly not that. So please, don't give pseudo code, give your whole code.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to write it understandable, but English not my first language. I replace all with real code from my order.component.ts. Thank you for your marks.

Comment: That's ok, I understand it isn't your native language, thank you for the code, I'll look at it

Comment: Can you also post your HTML code and the code of `OrderService` ?

Comment: I added all of it. Thank you for your attention to my code :)

Comment: No problem, last thing though, if you could post the code of the `Order` class ?

Comment: Add order.model.ts for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your error :

```
editOrder() {
  /* ... */
  this.orderContent.push({
    className: this[newClassFieldName].className,
    label: this[newClassFieldName].label,
    value: this[newClassFieldName].value
  });
}
```

More precisely :

```
this[newClassFieldName].className
```

When you write that, you try to read a variable in your `OrderComponent`.

This could have worked, because you declare that variable just before. But your issue is that you created variables into that variable, that have very strange names. The error tells you that :

```
Property 'className' does not exist on type 'this[keyof this]'
```

You declare the variable like this

```
let newClassFieldName: string = this.orderService.order.orderContent[item].className;
```

Just before that, could you write

```
console.log(this.orderService.order.orderContent[item].className);
```

And tell me the result ?

Comment: Thank you for your work. I added `console.log` ( I do it before, but try again), it's work fine. I get className like it should be. Compiler show my code line and it say my error in same place, but in `submit()` method on `className: this[item].className`. When I comment for cycle with (let item in this) in `submit()` all compiled success.

Comment: And if you make the console log into `submit`, you see the same className ? And could you try with an array, instead of creating variables in your component ?

Comment: I mark error lines in order.component.ts in my question for you. I try console.log and debug, and all works fine. I try it on my site and i can edit form and get right result on server and save in base. All works, but when i first run my Angular probram - compiler warring me.

Comment: I think that's happened, because compiler don't know what is `className: this[item].className`, before program run and order get it from `ngOnInit`. But what i should do with this, I don't know :(

Comment: Could you try this ? `className: this[newClassFieldName as any].className,`

Comment: Yes! It solve this. But i don't understand why it check this only on first run. I had working site all day and on next morning after first start all broke) Maybe compiler use deep check only for first start? Have you got any idea about this? In any case, many thanks for such a great work and your successful investigation.

Comment: No problem man ! and I don't know why it stopped working suddenly, but this syntax only accepts strings, so if you tell me that it works but the compiler don't like it, then I just force the compiler to like it !